# Trying to populate combobox from SQLite VB.NET Windows Universal App

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, combobox, win-universal-app

I am new to SQLite and I am trying to populate a ComboBox in a Windows Universal App from the database. I did the following so far:

```
        With cmbPaciente.Items
        Try
            Dim sConexao As String = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "\Banco\Pronto Facil.db")
            Dim aConexao As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(sConexao)
            Dim Comando = aConexao.Execute("select Nome from Dados_Pessoais")
            For Each item In Comando
                .Add(item)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            .Add("Text 1")
            .Add("Text 2")
        End Try
    End With
```

I am getting this error:

```
BC32023 Expression is of type 'Integer', which is not a collection type.
```

I understood thats because aConexao.Execute is returning an integer, but how else should I do it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong approach, this way it Works:

```
With cmbPaciente.Items
    Dim sConexao As String = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Deal.db")
    Dim aConexao As New SQLiteConnection(New SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sConexao)
    For Each item As Stockvb In aConexao.Table(Of Stockvb)()
        Dim newlist As New Stockvb()
        newlist.Id = item.Id
        newlist.Symbol = item.Symbol
        combolist.Add(newlist)
    Next
    cmbPaciente.ItemsSource = combolist
End With
```

And here is the Stockvb class:

```
Public Class Stockvb
<PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement>
Public Property Id() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_Id
    End Get
    Set
        m_Id = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Id As Integer

<MaxLength(8)>
Public Property Symbol() As String
    Get
        Return m_Symbol
    End Get
    Set
        m_Symbol = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Symbol As String
```

End Class

Special thanks to Grace Feng - MSFT